# Using sed to find, convert and replace lines

Tags: bash, replace, sed, find

I don't know too much of bash scripting and I'm trying to develop a bash script to do this operations:

- I have a lot of .txt files in the same directory.
- Every .txt file follows this structure:

> > file1.txt:
> >     <name>first operation</name>
> >     <operation>21</operation>
> >     <StartTime>1292435633</StartTime>
> >     <EndTime>1292435640</EndTime>
> >     <name>second operation</name>
> >     <operation>21</operation>
> >     <StartTime>1292435646</StartTime>
> >     <EndTime>1292435650</EndTime>

- I want to search every <StartTime> line and convert it to standard date/time format (not unix timestamp) but preserving the structure <StartTime>2010-12-15 22:52</StartTime>, for example. This could be a function of search/replace, using sed? I think I could use these function that I found: date --utc --date "1970-01-01 $1 sec" "+%Y-%m-%d %T"
- I want to to do the same with <EndTime> tag.
- I should do this for all *.txt files in a directory.

I tried using sed but with not wanted results. As I said I don't know so much of bash scripting so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for your help!

Regards

Comment: You can use `date -d @1292435640 ...`

Answer (score 1):

sed is incapable of doing date conversions; instead I would reccomend you to use a more appropriate tool like awk:

```
echo '<StartTime>1292435633</StartTime>' | awk '{
    match($0,/[0-9]+/);
    t = strftime("%F %T",substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),1);
    sub(/[0-9]+/,t)
} 
{print}'
```

If your input files have one tag per line, as in your structure example, it should work flawlessly.

If you need to repeat the operation for every .txt file just use a shell for:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    awk '/^<[^>]*Time>/{
        match($0,/[0-9]+/);
        t = strftime("%F %T",substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),1);
        sub(/[0-9]+/,t)
    } 1' "$file" >"$file.new"
    # mv "$file.new" "$file"
done
```

In comparison to the previous code, I have done two minor changes:

- added condition /^<[^>]*Time>/ that checks if the current line starts with  or
- converted {print} to the shorter '1'

If the files ending with .new contain the result you were expecting, you can uncomment the line containing mv.

Comment: Hi Marco, thank your for your answer.
I tried but the script returned me this error:
awk: cmd. line:2: fatal: 3 is invalid as number of arguments for strftime
awk: cmd. line:2: fatal: 3 is invalid as number of arguments for strftime
I don't know how awk works... could you help me?

Comment: Sorry my bad: strftime() is provided only by gnu-awk, I should have mentioned it. Are you using another implementation? By the way, since it is complaining about an invalid number of arguments in the call to strftime(), I would try removing the third one (e.g. strftime("%F %T",substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)) )

Comment: I'm using GNU Awk 3.1.5 on a SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 SP3

Comment: I tried removing the latest paramater as you said and now the script works without errors but the dates are still in unix timestamp format in the new files (*.txt.new). Maybe I have to install another version of awk?

Comment: It works without an error for me in gawk 3.1.6. You don't need to put the `print` statement in a separate set of braces.

Comment: Dennis, I installed gawk 3.1.6 and with the third parameter works fine but the timestamps in field <StartTime> are still in UNIX timestamp. Did in your tests changed? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe your input files have one or more spaces at the beginning of lines? Try changing condition /^<[^>]*Time>/ to /<[^>]*Time>/

Comment: Hi marco, Thank you, now all works fine!!! It changes the dates correctly and moves the file. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using grep:

```
while read line;do
    if [[ $line == *"<StartTime>"* || $line == *"<EndTime>"* ]];then
        n=$(echo $line | grep -Po '(?<=(>)).*(?=<)')
        line=${line/$n/$(date -d @$n)}
    fi

    echo $line >> file1.new.txt
done < file1.txt
```

---

```
$ cat file1.new.txt 
<name>first operation</name>
<operation>21</operation>
<StartTime>Wed Dec 15 18:53:53 CET 2010</StartTime>
<EndTime>Wed Dec 15 18:54:00 CET 2010</EndTime>

<name>second operation</name>
<operation>21</operation>
<StartTime>Wed Dec 15 18:54:06 CET 2010</StartTime>
<EndTime>Wed Dec 15 18:54:10 CET 2010</EndTime>
```